# Counting letters in a word

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Given the next word:

ABCABACBABACACBACBAC

What would be the most efficient way to count the letters that appear in the word using python?

(Solution: A:8, B:6, C:6)

Comment: collections.Counter(word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```py
>>> def counter(in_str):
...     out_dict = dict()
...     for char in in_str:
...             if char in out_dict:
...                     out_dict[char] += 1
...             else:
...                     out_dict[char] = 1
...     return out_dict
... 
>>> counter("ABCABACBABACACBACBAC")
{'A': 8, 'B': 6, 'C': 6}
>>>
```

If you want to give a try on how to implement things.

Comment: You could do for instance `out_dict[char] = out_dict.get(char, 0) + 1` to avoid the `if/else`. But there is already `collections.Counter`, a subclass of `dict` which does all that and is probably more optimised, so there is no need to implement your own function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel - just use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter
result = Counter('ABCABACBABACACBACBAC')
```